# Strange PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a function which fetches the user details from the MySQL database.
If the supplied function argument is an integer, the function treat it as a user id, if argument is an string it checks if string is a key in a predefined array, if the argument is a key in the array then it treats the argument as user_group id(fetched from config file), if the argument is string but not in the array keys, then it treats the argument as username, if none of the conditions are met it throws an error.

**Problem** : If I supply a username (string) to the function it works as it should. If I supply a string which is a key in the predefined array then it works. 
If I supply user id (int) it works for all ids but **1**. That is, if `$param` is 1 it gives me 'Error 3' (below in the code) if supplied integer is anything else which is an id in the database then it works.
The id **1** does exist in the database. The strange thing is that, the var_dump() actually dumps the correct data even if the supplied id is 1.

This is the last query string : SELECT * FROM `user` as `u` JOIN `user_details` as `ud` ON `u`.`id` = `ud`.`id_user` WHERE `u`.`username` = '1'

Clearly it's treating 1 as a string instead of integer. **Why ?** And why it is still fetching the first record (id=1) although it is treating the id as username `u`.`username` = '1'?

If I add `$param = 1;` at the start of the `function _initialize ( $param )` then I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 49 bytes) in
>   E:\APACHE\htdocs\codeigniter\lib\system\database\DB_query_builder.php
>   on line 2677

```
protected function _initialize ( $param )
{

    $this->ci->db->select (  '*'  );
    $this->ci->db->from ( $this->tableUser [ 'table' ] . ' as u' );
    $compare = NULL;

    if (  is_int ( $param )  ){
        $compare = $this->tableUser [ 'column' ] [ 'id' ];
    }
    elseif ( is_string ( $param ) && array_key_exists (  $param, $this->constantsServices  )  ){
        $compare = $this->tableUser [ 'column' ] [ 'id_user_groups' ];
        $param = $this->constantsServices [ $param ];
    }
    else if (  is_string ( $param )  ){
        $compare = $this->tableUser [ 'column' ] [ 'username' ];
    }else {
        throw new Exception ( 'Error 1' );
    }


    $this->ci->db->where ( 'u.' . $compare, $param );
    $this->ci->db->join (  $this->tableUserDetails [ 'table' ] . ' as ud', 'u.' . $this->tableUser [ 'column' ] [ 'id' ] . ' = ud.' . $this->tableUserDetails [ 'column' ] [ 'id_user' ]  );
    $query = $this->ci->db->get (  );

    if ( ! $query ){
        throw new Exception ( 'Error 2' );
    }

    $data = $query->unbuffered_row('array');

    var_dump ( $data );

    if ( !isset ( $data ) ){
        throw new Exception ( 'Error 3' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend trying to give this question a better title to attract people who will be able to help you.

Comment: @TomHart That's a good idea, thanks, but am pretty bad at titles :(

Comment: preg_match isn't inherently a better or worse way to test for a numeric value. It's just a different way. If you're looping, is_numeric or (maybe better for whole numbers) ctype_digit is probably better as far as resources. Just out of curiosity, what happens if you comment out the first elseif block?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the regex to findout the numeric / digit value. 
instead of `is_int` use

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$param))
{
    //Your code goes here
    // Then typecast your parameter as 
    $param = (int)$param
}
```

Comment: This gives me error : `> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 580 bytes) in E:\APACHE\htdocs\codeigniter\lib\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 221`

Comment: Can you try to echo query and count records in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yup I did, it is mentioned in the question. Seems like the memory allocation problem is arising somewhere from a loop I guess.

Comment: plus one for a better way to test for numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

[is_int checks if the variable is a php int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) So, if a string is passed, you get false. Try using [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and maybe cast it to int instead.

This won't address the issues you're  having with memory.